# How to use cookies when building a website with login feature?

Tags: jquery, html, cookies

I am planning to build a website which will allow users to login. Based on their login credentials, I will display different user information on their account page. I already have a API server set up for that. I just need help with storing their login info while they're on my website.

Comment: Security is **hard**.  Do not reinvent the wheel.  You should use an existing authentication system.

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all I would recommend you to not only post a question to stackoverflow but to actually **show** what you have tried out so far.

I am not sure on which level of programming you are right now but I would definitely recommend some type of framework here that makes working with stuff like security much easier.

Maybe you have heard about http://laravel.com/ or http://ellislab.com/codeigniter before and those are only two examples.

I dont want to state which one fits your needs best but I have used laravel for a few applications now and I can definitely say that it lets you make the things you want to do in minutes.

I hope, this will be of help to you. Feel free to ask me anyting in the comments below.

Comment: i dont think i need php because i have an api server that will handle everything.

Comment: i was thinking more along the lines of storing user's username in a cookie after they log in and then send cookie data to my api server to get responding data.

Comment: Hm. Since this is not the way I'd tackle this I dont think I further help you on this issue.